# Facebook authentication error in Heroku based django website

Tags: python, django, facebook, heroku, python-social-auth

I have fully created a Django website with python-social-auth for facebook authentication and have hosted it on heroku(free version). The problem however is,that my Facebook authentication,which was working perfectly locally,is not working and it throws an error as follows:-

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

I have configured my facebook settings , wherein the site url is the one hosted on heroku (https://quiet-hamlet-3248.herokuapp.com/). Also,I haven't changed my API keys/secret.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured it out.

As mentioned  [here](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html)  , one needs to update his settings file to include the line SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True 
This is because heroku fails to pass the headers required to identify the app.